# register new types to a storage system using extension methods

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

I have multiple classes that need to be stored. At the moment they are stored in json but this will eventually change.
I want the serialization/storage code, separated from the actual code of the class, so when we, for instance, move from local json files to cloud SQL, the base class does not need to be edited.

My plan was to add the ToJson method as an extension in a new file. This fits the requirements nicely.

I have an JsonStorageManager that tries to store objects. All items that can be stored implement IStorable.

```
public interface IStorageManager{
   public void Save();
}

public interface IStorable{
   public string StorageKey; //in the event of SQL will keep ID, in the event of json is the path
}

public class JsonStorageManager : IStorageManager
{
   public void Save(IStorable obj)
   {
       //here I need to check if the actual type of obj, actually has the required extension
       //in order to be serialized;
       JsonSerializer.SaveToFile(obj,StorageKey, obj. **ToJson()**) //path, string

                                     //here is the issue since IStorable does not have .ToJson()
                                              
   }
}
```

In the other side the classes to be stored look like:

```
in file MyDataSet.cs:

public class MyDataSet : IStorable {
   public string StorageKey = "filename.json";
}

in a file at StorageManagers/JsonStorageManagers/Extensions/MyDataSetJsonExtension.cs

static class MyDataSetExtension
{
   public static string ToJson(this MyDataSet set)
   {
       return Json.Serialize.WhateverIsNeededHere(set);
   }
}
```

The plan would be that all types that need to be saved with Json, create the extension method file extension. In this way, to add new types one does not need to edit nor the existing MyDataSet class, nor the JsonStorageManager. Just add new files.

How would I access the extension method? How can I make a proper structure that allow it?

Comment: So your question is?

Comment: How can I structure the whole thing so I can do obj.ToJson() then if the actual object does not have the extension implemented an exception is thrown. If the actual object has the extension it is called.

Comment: That sounds quite fragile. Why not just put the extension method on `IStorable` instead of each individual type and then you will find all your issues at compile time instead of runtime errors?

Comment: because not all classes need the same shared code for storing it. And IStorable will also be IStorable for SQL so .ToJson method does not sound like belonging there...

Comment: Normally I would avoid opining on implementation details, however, you should avoid runtime errors at all costs. By implementing the feature as you describe and therefore moving error prevention from compile time to runtime, you are setting your future self up for failure. You should consider implementing an interface or base class instead.

Comment: I'm totally open to suggestions on this direction. I just cannot define an architecture that allows me to add new classes without editing the JsonStorageManager. And new storage systems (SQL)without editing MyDataSet class. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I structure the whole thing so I can do obj.ToJson() then if the actual object does not have the extension implemented an exception is thrown. If the actual object has the extension it is called.

If you have access to `IStorable` you should *heavily* consider implementing it there such as:

```cs
interface IStorable
{
    string Serialize();
}
```

If for some reason you have no access to change any of the associated classes, extensions might are not a good choice. Extensions are little more than a compile-time concept to make it easier to use shared code while writing it and any attempt to dynamically find them at runtime would be fragile and hard to maintain.

If you still want to continue the route of dynamically finding the right extension/serializer at runtime you could do a couple of different things. We could use reflection or just a plain dependency injection, among others.

Using context from your question and comments I wrote this in a way to not change the class or method signatures of your already defined classes.

### Dependency Injection

Consider injecting some form of serializer "finder" into the `IStorageManager` class. Again I would just recommend taking another look at changing the interfaces you already have, but if you have no ability to change these I wrote an example of just one or many things that might get the result you are looking for.

```cs
void Main()
{
    // create the group and register any serializers,
    // has compile time saftey with the generic constraint of .Register<T>
    // and generic constrains of Func<>
    var serializerGroup = new SerializerGroup();

    serializerGroup.Register<MyDataSet>(MyDataSetExtension.ToJson);
    
    // inject it into the manager class so we dont have to change the signature
    JsonStorageManager manager = new(serializerGroup);
}

public interface ISerializerGroup
{
    /// Attempts to find a function that will serialize the provided object
    public bool TryGetSerializer(IStorable obj, out Func<IStorable,string> serializer);
}

public class SerializerGroup : ISerializerGroup
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<IStorable, string>> serializers = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IStorable, string>>();

    public bool TryGetSerializer(IStorable obj, out Func<IStorable, string> serializer)
    {
        Type type = obj?.GetType();

        if (serializers.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            serializer = serializers[type];
            return true;
        }

        serializer = default;
        return false;
    }

    // we add compile time saftey here by constraining our generic types
    public void Register<T>(Func<IStorable, string> serializer) where T : IStorable
    {
        if (serializer is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serializer));
        }

        serializers.Add(typeof(T),serializer);
    }
}

public class JsonStorageManager : IStorageManager
{
    private readonly ISerializerGroup serializers;

    // instead of modifing this class' signature we can just inject the
    // dependency and keep the "finder" implementation detail abstracted
    public JsonStorageManager(ISerializerGroup serializers)
    {
        this.serializers = serializers ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serializers));
    }

    public void Save(IStorable obj)
    {
        // try to get a serializer, if we fail throw an error
        if (serializers.TryGetSerializer(obj, out Func<IStorable,string> serializer) is false)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Some meaningful error here");
        }

        JsonSerializer.SaveToFile(obj, obj.StorageKey, serializer.Invoke(obj));
    }
}
```